# Change DefaultTask if some settings already exist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Windows phone 8 app, instead of always opening the application with same PhoneApplicationPage, I need to switch the initial view. i.e. Home page if settings already exists and settings page if the user opens the app for the first time.

How should I go about it?

Currently the way I adopted is :

Made Default task empty in WMAppManifest.xml

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default"  />
```

Decided which page to move to in Application_Launching event handler.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    if (SettingFileExists())
        RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    else
        RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Settings.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Is this the best way to approach this scenario? Is there any potential issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a re lots of different ways of doing this and no one "best" way.

My personal preference is to use a custom `UriMapper` that does the redirect on start up.
E.g.

- Set the Navigation startup Uri to something special that doesn't exist. e.g. "StartUp"
- Set a custom UriMapper:

  ```
      RootFrame.UriMapper = new MyUriMapper();
  ```
- Then in the UriMapper check for the special uri and take appropriate action:

  ```
  public class MyUriMapper : UriMapperBase
  {
      public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
      {
          if (uri.OriginalString == "/StartUp")
          {
              if (!this.dataOperations.IsLoggedIn())
              {
                  return Login.Path;
              }
              else
              {
                  return Main.Path;
              }
          }

          return uri;
      }
  }
  ```